# populate a value of a row into a new column partitioned by date

Tags: sql, teradata

I have 5 columns i want to create a 6th column with value of 'x5 row' of $ column partitioned by date.

As of now only way i see is unpivot it and put each $ value into separate columns.

But is it possible to make column 6 using some reference?

```
date    sort    category    %   $                   6 th column(to be created)
1/31/2017   0   x1  5.27478     5,406,339,989.60    -31,567,300
1/31/2017   4   x2  5.03073     -21,611,583.57      -31,567,300
1/31/2017   3   x3  5.91494     4,122,330.91        -31,567,300
1/31/2017   1   x4  5.34965     5,754,418,975.28    -31,567,300
1/31/2017   5   x5  5.29412     -31,567,300         -31,567,300
1/31/2017   2.2 x6  7.99999     -250,488.32         -31,567,300
1/31/2017   6   x7  6.16547     -4,984,148.73       -31,567,300
2/28/2017   4   x1  5.04686     -20,182,279.41      5,807,539,814.96
2/28/2017   2.2 x2  5.33533     -176,195.29         5,807,539,814.96
2/28/2017   6   x3  6.13669     -3,455,249.32       5,807,539,814.96
2/28/2017   2.1 x4  5.48088     49,709,482.70       5,807,539,814.96
2/28/2017   1   x5  5.27017     5,807,539,814.96    5,807,539,814.96
2/28/2017   0   x6  5.34965     5,754,418,975.28    5,807,539,814.96
2/28/2017   3   x7  5.32231     23,327,653.12       5,807,539,814.96
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function (in this case `MIN` but `MAX` would work equally well) to select only the value of `$` when category is `x5`:

```
SELECT *,
       MIN(CASE WHEN category = 'x5' THEN Dollar END) OVER (PARTITION BY date) AS "6th Column"
FROM data
```

Note I've assumed your `$` column is actually called `Dollar`, you can change as necessary.

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ed8f5/1) (for SQL Server but should work fine on Teradata)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to get what you require,

```
      SELECT a.*,b.$2
      FROM TABLE a
      LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT Date,sum($) as $2
      FROM Table 
      WHERE category = 'x5'
      GROUP BY  Date) b
      on a.Date=b.Date
```